# angularjs ui calendar not displaying added event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add a new events to the ui calendar using ui bootstrap modal box. However, its not showing on the calendar. Below I  have created the function for the day click event which contains the code for the modal box:

```
$scope.dayClickEvent = function(date,jsEvent,view){

       //open model view for adding a event title
      var creatEventModalInstance = $modal.open({
              templateUrl: '/js/schedule/event_modal.html',
              controller: function($scope, $modalInstance){

                  $scope.add = function(event){

                       $modalInstance.close(event);
                  };


                  $scope.close = function(){

                       $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                  };
              }

     });
```

Here is the code for the ui configuration for the calendar:

```
 $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar:{
                  height:   450,
                  editable: true,
        header:{
                  left:   'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
                  center: 'title',
                  right:   'today prev,next'
      },
         dayClick: $scope.dayClickEvent
    }
};
```

Also the code for the event source to provide ui calendar with data about the events:

```
 $scope.eventSources = {
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Event1',
                start: '2015-01-18'
            },
            {
                title: 'dsadas',
                start: '2015-01-18'
            }

            // etc...
        ],
        color: 'yellow',   // an option!
        textColor: 'black' // an option!
    };
```

So, what I am doing wrong and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

$scope.eventSources is an *array* that includes one or more event source *objects*.
It's an extended form meant to allow you to add multiple event sources.

an [Event Source Object](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/) includes the `events` array as well as any [Event Source Options](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/#options) related to the events - such as text or background colours.

Therefore you must to add an *object* for *each* event source
- then you include your `events` array *within* the  object - along with any options.

...in your example you put the `events` array directly within an `$scope.eventSources` *object*...

To correct:
- make `$scope.eventSources` an array ie use [square brackets]
- put the `events:[]` array inside an object ie within {curly brackets}

try something like this:

```
$scope.eventSources = [
    //this is event source object #1
    {
        events: [ // put the array in the `events` property
            {
                title: 'Event1',
                start: '2015-01-24'
            },
            {
                title: 'Event2',
                start: '2015-01-28'
            }
        ],
        color: 'black',     // an Event Source Option!
        textColor: 'yellow' // an Event Source Option!
    }
];
```

as outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380314/angularjs-full-calendar-doesnt-display-events) answer, you can add multiple sources by referencing objects, like:

```
$scope.eventSources = [$scope.eventSourceObject1, $scope.eventSourceObject2, etc...],
```

(you can call your  Event Source Objects whatever you want, as long as they're correctly constructed)

Again each event source will have to be an object that *includes* the `events` array inside.